# Are there any preferable stats for World vs World combat?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am currently leveling my Guardian, and even though I'm not yet level 80, I'm already planning my gear in upfront.

Since I really like World vs World, I was wondering whether it's better to be a "Glass Cannon" or a "Tanky" in this brutal environment.

I may be wrong, but World vs World seems to me to be a place where numbers are better than quality when it comes to players - in that more players is better than well geared players. Am I wrong in this?

So theoretically, being able to stay alive longer would be better for the team.

Which are the "better" stats to stack when doing Player vs Player in Guild Wars 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a casual WvW player I would say:

```
Stack the stats that fit your play style.
```

The thing with WvW is that you usually are in a pretty big group, and what you don't have, others can provide instead. As for me, I play as a total glass cannon (elementalist with power + precision + crit damage) and I do a LOT of damage from the back. I depend on the tanky (vitality/thoughness) characters in front while they in turn depend on us healing/dps squishies behind.

And you are right that numbers are important. As long as you have the numbers I wouldn't worry too much about being downed, or even killed, since you easily can get resurrected. More important is to die in a good spot where help can reach you.

Numbers doesn't always help though, since crowd psychology also plays a role. A small aggressive group can rout a much bigger group that doesn't have enough confidence.

Comment: So Teorically, the tip is to stack the stats i feel confortable with ? Lets say i'm into critical and condition damage, you would advise me to stack those and jump into WvW ?

Comment: Yes and yes, as long as you are aware of your strengths and weaknesses and not aim for the "tanky" approach. Then you can seek out the situations where you excel and play it to maximum advantage: critical+condition sounds like some kind of DoT monster and that definitely sounds feasible.